# How to compile C in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I want to make sure that the project is configured entirely for C **(NOT C++)**. I cannot find any accurate walk through for doing this. I am open to using `Eclipse`, except that it does not create a working project out of the box (which makes no sense...).

Comment: MSVS 2010 fully supports "C".  All you need to do is use ".c" suffix in your source file.  As MByD said, you can also specify "/Tc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add [/Tc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx) as a command line option.

Comment: Where do I do this? (I have actually wondered how to add command line options for a while..)

Comment: I am not next to it, but it should be: `right click on the project -> properties -> c/c++ ` then either the command line tab or the compiler tab, I am not sure. sorry.

Comment: In fact it's `right click on the project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As`. There you can select /TC as MByD suggests.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know Visual Studio will treat all sources that end in .c as C source. So you should be fine right out of the box. Are you experiencing a particular problem?