# Creating function out of realloc() function

Tags: c, arrays, function, realloc

I would like to create a function that will reallocate 2D array of `typedef struct`

```
typedef struct hero_data{
    char name[254];
    char title[254];
    int encoding;
    int startstr;
    double incstr;
    int startdex;
    double incdex;
    int startintel;
    double incintel;
    int basemindmg,basemaxdmg;
    double bat;
    double basearmor;
    struct hero_data *next;
    struct hero_data *Class;
}hero;

typedef struct parameters{ 
    int toughtotal;
    int nimbletotal;
    int smarttotal;
    int skeptictotal;
    int mystictotal;
    int cursedtotal;
    int brutetotal;
    int shreddertotal;
    int vanillatotal;
    int typetotal;
    int typenum;
    hero **smart[];
    hero **nimble[];
    hero **tough[]; 
    hero **type[][];
    hero **skeptic[][];
    hero **mystic[][];
    hero **cursed[][];
    hero **brute[][];
    hero **shredder[][];
    hero **vanilla[][];
}Parameters;

void reallocation(Parameters *p, int typenum,int typetotal)
{
    int i;

    p = realloc(p,sizeof(Parameters *) * typenum);
    for ( i = 0; i < typenum; i++)
    {
        p[i] = realloc(p[i],sizeof(Parameters) * typetotal);
    }
}
```

The function above shall be called like: `void reallocation(p->type,p->typenum,p->typetotal);`

So, by substituting the parameters of the function correctly, I expect the function to look like:

```
void reallocation(Parameters *p, int typenum,int typetotal)
{
    int i;

    p->type = realloc(p->type,sizeof(Parameters *) * p->typenum);
    for ( i = 0; i < p->typenum; i++)
    {
        p->type[i] = realloc(p->type[i],sizeof(Parameters) * p->typetotal);
    }
}
```

The typedef struct named `Parameters` contains `int typenum`, `int typetotal`, and the 2D arrays that shall be initialized through `realloc()`.

When I try to compile, I am getting an error in Tiny C (Windows): *The file is in C.

1. Error: cannot cast 'struct parameters' to 'void *'

   (This apeears in the 'p[i] = realloc(p[i],sizeof(Parameters) * typetotal')

Can anyone help me re-write this function so that I will be able to realloc the 2D arrays within the `Parameter *p`?

---

I tried changing `void reallocation(Parameters *p, ...)` into `void reallocation(Parameters *p[], ...)` and the Error # 2 becomes the same message as Error #1 and it appears in the `=` of `p[i] = realloc (...);`

Comment: realloc returns a void *, so needs a cast. But more importantly, what are you trying to do? Change something inside a single Parameter?

Comment: @doctorlove My program needs to initialize around nine 2D arrays that are within typedef struct named `Parameter`. I just wanted to reallocate each one of them by putting the names of the arrays in `void reallocation (Parameters *p |<- Here|, ...)`

Comment: If you had a way to initialize, allocate, then free existing structs, then would it work for you to use the same functions that accomplised those tasks, within a new function "reallocation", to accomplish the re-allocation?  i.e. just include the free and allocate functions, with new parameters?  Also, it is important that your argument list follow a prescribed set, or are you free to choose what argument you want to use?  (that is, is this an assignment with prescribed requirements?)

Comment: @ryyker I plan to use the `reallocation` function to initialize the arrays and re-allocate their memory since `int typenum` and `int typetotal` increases when conditions are met within the code. And I realized I needed to repear the re-allocating function over and over again.

Comment: It looks like you are compiling it with a C++ compiler. These error messages are typical for C++.

Comment: @n.m. I tried compiling same code with Tiny C, and in the line `p[i] = realloc(p[i],sizeof(Parameters) * typetotal)` the error message is: "cannot cast 'struct parameters' to 'void *'

Comment: That's a C error. You need to fix it but you need to start using a C compiler first.

Comment: @n.m okay, I will start using Tiny C. But do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Update your question with C error messages, and replace your description of the Parameters struct with a declaration copied from the actual code.

Comment: Your `Parameters` struct makes no sense at all, and is not in fact legal C. It's hard to tell what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @n.m.Fixed. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Not in the slightest. I've no clue how did you manage to avoid getting tons of error messages on all the `hero` fields of your struct. Not even speaking about what you actually *want* to do with them. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large problem with your code is that you are assigning inequal types to each other, and you are also not checking the result of `realloc`. If this call were to fail, you will leak the memory allocated initially.

Assuming that your struct looks like

```
typedef struct {
    int typenum;
    int typetotal;
} Parameters;

Parameters *p;

p = malloc(10 * sizeof(*p));
if (p == NULL)
    printf("Allocatation of memory failed!\n");
```

To properly reallocate to say 20, you could do something like this

```
reallocate_p(&p, 20);
```

Where the function is defined as

```
void reallocate_p(Parameters **p, int new_size)
{
    Parameters *temp;

    temp = realloc(*p, sizeof(*temp) * new_size);
    if (temp==NULL) {
        printf("Reallocatation of memory failed!\n");
        // Handle error        
    }

    *p = temp;

    return;
}
```

Also note that we don't cast the return value of `malloc()` and `realloc()`.
As to why, see this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: why do you need to put `int i` when your code is not using it?

Comment: I added `for ( i = 0; i < typenum; i ++) {temp = realloc(*p, sizeof(*temp) * typetotal);}` below `temp = realloc(*p, ...);`. I tried using that void function by calling: `reallocate_p(p->type,p->typenum,p->typetotal);` and I am getting Warning: assignement from incompatible pointer type. Any help?

Comment: You keep writing `p->type` but in your definition of `Parameters` there is no member called `type`.

Comment: What I tried to refer `p->type` as was the `hero **type[][]`. How do I do this then?

Comment: Ok, at this point it starts to be clear to me that there is a lot going wrong with your code. More so than can be easily covered in this question. I could take maybe take a look at it over email if you want

Comment: Thanks! Can you leave your email address here so that I could email to you my code

Answer (score 1):

OP is coding in C, but using a using a C++ compiler.

Code in C++

```
// C 
// p = realloc(p,sizeof(Parameters *) * typenum);
// C++
p = (Parameters *) realloc(p,sizeof(Parameters *) * typenum);
```

**OR**

VS2012: set properties for each C file to use C compiler

[How to compile C in visual studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919076/how-to-compile-c-in-visual-studio-2010)

---

OP code has a memory leak when scaling down the pointer array table.  The pointers in the table that are about to be loss due to `realloc()` need to be freed first.

```
for (i=old_typenum; i<typenum; i++) free(p[i]);
p = realloc(p,sizeof(Parameters *) * typenum);
```

Comment: The configuration of VS has already been made before, but I do not know why it is giving me c++ errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "old_typenum" ?

Comment: @Beginner C To properly reallocate the pointer array, the re-allocation routine needs to know the old size of the array.  With `realloc()`, this information is hidden from the user.  Since you have a more complex type (an array of pointers that in turn point to data) and you _may_ re-allocate to a _smaller_ array of pointers, the excess pointers need to have the data they point to freed.  Ah - I see you have all ready selected a solution.  Good luck.